# Model Property set in controller not showing up in view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

This is a pretty simple example.

controller

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult MyPage(MyModelClass myModel) {
    myModel.someProperty = "b";
    return view(myModel)
}
```

The typed view contains a hidden field for someProperty

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.someProperty)
```

The Get controller sets someProperty to "a"

Yet after a post the value of someProperty in the view is still "a"

That doesn't seem rigth to me.  Any insights?    Thx

Answer (score 4):

`ModelState` keeps the posted value 'a'. And as it has higher priority in populating model values (than the model itself), view renders 'a'. You could remove value from ModelState and let model value be used

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPage(MyModelClass myModel) {
    myModel.someProperty = "b";

    ModelState.Remove("someProperty");    

    return view(myModel);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can actually reproduce this (which surprised me initially), but after some head scratching, I think it makes sense.

Setting a breakpoint on the line `myModel.SomeProperty = "b";` does show that the property is set correctly.  That leads me to believe MVC is making an assumption based on the fact that you're rendering a view as a direct result of a POST (i.e. there is existing modelstate).  I'd imagine it's because if you're redisplaying a view after a POST, the assumption is that you're doing so because the form contains errors.  By fetching the values from the modelstate, the form can be correctly repopulated for the user to try again.

Edit:  And of course, as soon as I post, I find an article that describes it better than I can: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

Comment: Interesting that you mention using html.DisplayFor since those values do not bind to the model, e.g. if I post to a controller like the one in my example, the displayfor properties will be null.

Comment: @user1337078 Actually, having just looked into that again it seems that paragraph is pretty misleading, so I'll edit my answer.  `Html.DisplayFor` doesn't bind at all, as you correctly pointed out, meaning the property would be set as normal rather than having anything to do with the modelstate.

Comment: After reading that blog I understand the problem, but I do not feel that it is a good assumption that all post backs are the result of validation errors.  I will start a new thread to get into that.  THX again!

Comment: @user1337078 It's not that "all post backs are the result of validation errors", it's that when you _directly pass the input model into, and return, the same view from a POST_, you usually do so because the user has made an error.  It's a very common scenario.  If it's not an error, you can always take the data, modifying it if you wish and pass it to another action, using that to build another model.  That's also common for data entry scenarios which require multiple "screens".